# Stored procedure with multiple updates, insert and deletes. What happens if last DML command fails?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

So, if I have multiple DML commands inside a stored procedure in SQL Server, if the last one fails, will all the other ones rollback? Considering I am not inside a transaction scope!

Comment: No - thats what a transaction is for.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarifying that.

Comment: If you don't have an explicit transaction, then each SQL statement will run inside its own implicit transaction. The trigger failing will **only** rollback the transaction it's running in that caused it to fire, e.g. that single SQL statement that caused the trigger to fire will be rolled back - nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your stored procedure to use `TRY CATCH` and a TRANSACTION .

```
BEGIN TRAN
BEGIN TRY

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- if error, roll back any changes done by any of the SQL statements
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END CATCH
```

Refer to this
http://techfunda.com/howto/192/transaction-in-stored-procedure